# How can I get pixel data from a window with Golang

Tags: windows, go, pixel

I want to make a program where I can read the pixel data from a window, for example a browser window or game window. Is there a way I can implement this with Golang? Probably the format I would like it in would be a 2d array of some sort that gives RGB values too.

Comment: You could take a screenshot with something like https://github.com/vova616/screenshot and then try to get the RGB values at the exact pixel.

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: @Flimzy it is for windows